# How do I enable fully qualified column names in Query Builder in Toad for Oracle?

Tags: database-administration, toad

I've found several hits on google on how to do this in Toad for SQL, but I need the same for Toad for Oracle. (Toad v11).

I'm building a large query where I combine several aliases of the same table (a Kimball-style datamart). I have hundreds of fields, and need to fully qualify each one for the final query.

I've looked through every setting in View-Toad Options, but I can't find anything that seems to do the trick.